# how to retrieve the value of the input query textbox in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

example I have a textbox input, the contents of the input textbox custom query of the user what the user inputted, an example in the textbox, I try to enter text "select id, name, country from the country" .. from the sql query on the results of the 3 coloumn of the country table, I asked how to take the number of columns, the column name of the textbox custom input .. to the number of columns I want to show in the textbox and the number of rows in the gridview appropriate number of columns in a query, for the names of the columns I want to display in gridview ..

```
 private void BindReportColumn(String report_id)
{
    dt = mda.GetData("SELECT column_name,column_text,size,back_color,fore_color FROM report_column INNER JOIN report ON report_column.report_id = report.report_id and report.report_id='" + report_id + "'", connStr).Tables[0];
     GridCustomColumn.DataSource = dt;
    GridCustomColumn.DataBind();
}
  private void addcolumn()
    {
        int i;
        //Add the items to the gridview

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //Assign the viewstate to the datatable
            if (!IsNumeric(txtcolumn_count.Text)) txtcolumn_count.Text = "0";
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["columnreport"];

            for (i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(txtcolumn_count.Text); i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                //dr["report_id"] = txtreport_id.Text;
                dr["column_name"] = "";
                dr["column_text"] = " ";
                dr["size"] = 0;
                dr["back_color"] = "";
                dr["fore_color"] = "";
                //Add the datarow to the datatable
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                //Now bind the datatable to the gridview
                GridCustomColumn.DataSource = dt;
                GridCustomColumn.DataBind();


                //Add the details to viewstate also
                ViewState["columnreport"] = dt;
            }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Provide an example what you want ?

Comment: difficult to explain, can in this thread through a picture?

Comment: yes you can paste a picture

Comment: through which to insert my picture? sorry i'm new here

Comment: There is an icon on top of editor next to braces {}

Comment: very long time to upload pictures, what if by email?

Comment: Well i am in office so don't have access to email.

Comment: I will try to explain one by one, hope you're understand

Comment: I have a textbox that the name txtquery, txtcount, in txtquery I try to enter text "select id, name, country from the country" . the results of The column is 3 , namely : id, name, country.. the number of columns I want to show in the txtcount and the number of rows in the gridview appropriate number of columns in a query, for the names of the columns I want to display in gridview

Comment: wait a minutes , i'll try to upload an image again

Comment: i need at least 10 reputation to post images. :(

Comment: have you found some solution ?